# Bootstrap radio button changing url

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, radio-button

I am working with cakePHP and bootstrap radio button, and would like to know how I can redirect the radio buttons onclick to different pages

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="radio"  name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked>  Individual
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Company </a>
        </label>

    </div>
```

this are the code for my radio button , but I would like to know how to use javascript to redirect to another page/url or is there any way in cakephp, please show me how to do it .
Can I use this way ?

```
<script>
  $('#option1').on('click', function () {
    // how do I redirect now ? //
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just set a new url in `location.href`?

Comment: I did not understand, can you show me what you mean ? like writing  the code

Answer (score 0):

You just need a normal js redirect, you should use the CakePHP router to make sure the link is correct (if it's an internal link):

```
<script>
$("input[name='options']").click(function(){
//$('#option1').on('click', function () {
    // how do I redirect now ? //
    window.location.href = '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'your_controller', 'action' => 'your_action')); ?>';
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I put controller as user and action as the page I wanted to get directed which is add2 ..
<script>
  $('#option1').on('click', function () {
    
    window.location.href = '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'add2')); ?>';
  })
</script>
but still did not work , dont know why

Comment: Looks like you need to post data, is this correct? If so then you need to submit the form and not redirect it... (https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: no I just need to change to different pages while clicking the tab, I tried fixing it like this but still doesnt work ..
<script>
  $('#option1').on('click', function () {
    
    window.location.href = "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'add2')); ?>";
  })
</script>

Comment: I didn't noticed it was a radio input! Edited my answer, it works now... or check this: https://jsfiddle.net/hugot77/3pg5bwr4/